# jQuery toggleClass on only one div outside the clicked div, not all with the same class

Tags: jquery, html

Have been trying for some time now & read all the other questions related to this but can't find an easy answer.

I have a row with 3 cols (not a table, bootstrap). The last col has an i icon with the class `edit`. When I click it, I want the div underneath the row to toggle the class `d-none` (so make it visible or not visible upon click). This works, but it makes all the divs with the same class visible, I just want to make the one div with the same class visible.

I tried the parent, next, find, closest etc methods, all not working.

```js
var edit_link = $('.edit');
var edit_box = $('.edit-box');

edit_link.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  edit_box.toggleClass('d-none');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 text-right text-primary">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt edit"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons row d-none edit-box">
  block I want shown when clicked on the edit pencil
</div>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `edit_box` holds a jQuery object containing *all* `.edit-box` elements. Instead you need to use DOM traversal to find the one related to the `edit_link` instance which was clicked.

To do that you can use `closest()` to get the nearest `.row`, then `next()`. Try this:

```js
var $edit_link = $('.edit');

$edit_link.on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').next('.buttons').toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 text-right text-primary">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt edit">Pencil</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons row d-none edit-box">
  block I want shown when clicked on the edit pencil
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2 text-right text-primary">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt edit">Pencil</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons row d-none edit-box">
  block I want shown when clicked on the edit pencil
</div>
```